# How to delete a podcast episode without advancing to the end

Tags: podcasts, ios, iphone

I listen to podcasts on my iPhone X. Sometimes I want to delete a podcast episode mid-listen and not finish it. I can see and delete unplayed episodes or fully played episodes, but cannot figure out how to delete episodes that I haven't finished. How can this be done? Is it possible but something in settings is preventing it?

My workaround is to advance the player to the last few seconds of the episode, let it finish playing, then delete it.

Comment: I'm midway thru a podcast on my X running ios11.1.2. I can swipe from right to left on the episode from the Library or tap the ellipsis (...) and select Remove from the menu to delete that podcast.  The only time I can't delete/remove it is if it's not downloaded to begin with.

Comment: @fsb - Tried the variation noted in your reply, and 'tis true.